# Failed to determine the health of the cluster when initial password setting in ElasticSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, config

I tried to install ElasticSearch on AWS ec2
I tried to set up initial password of ElasticSearch with following command and got this error message

```
/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin

$ ./elasticsearch-reset-password -u elasticsearch
ERROR: Failed to determine the health of the cluster.
```

Here is my elasticsearch.yml file

```
======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:#
#cluster.name: aaaaaaa
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
##node.name: ${HOSTNAME}
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
# Path to log files:
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
# 
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# By default Elasticsearch is only accessible on localhost. Set a different
# address here to expose this node on the network:
#
#network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
#network.publish_host: ${HOSTNAME}
network.host: ["0.0.0.0"]
#
# By default Elasticsearch listens for HTTP traffic on the first free port it
# finds starting at 9200. Set a specific HTTP port here:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts:  - ${HOSTNAME}
discovery.type: single-node
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_master_nodes:  - ${HOSTNAME}
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Readiness ----------------------------------
#
# Enable an unauthenticated TCP readiness endpoint on localhost
#
#readiness.port: 9399
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Allow wildcard deletion of indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: false

#----------------------- BEGIN SECURITY AUTO CONFIGURATION -----------------------
#
# The following settings, TLS certificates, and keys have been automatically
# generated to configure Elasticsearch security features on 22-10-2022 08:48:06
#
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Enable security features
xpack.security.enabled: true

xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true

# Enable encryption for HTTP API client connections, such as Kibana, Logstash, and Agents
xpack.security.http.ssl:
  enabled: true
  keystore.path: certs/http.p12

# Enable encryption and mutual authentication between cluster nodes
xpack.security.transport.ssl:
  enabled: true
  verification_mode: certificate
  keystore.path: certs/transport.p12
  truststore.path: certs/transport.p12
# Create a new cluster with the current node only
# Additional nodes can still join the cluster later
# cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["aaaaaaa"]

# Allow HTTP API connections from anywhere
# Connections are encrypted and require user authentication
http.host: 0.0.0.0

# Allow other nodes to join the cluster from anywhere
# Connections are encrypted and mutually authenticated
#transport.host: 0.0.0.0

#----------------------- END SECURITY AUTO CONFIGURATION -------------------------
```

################################################################################################################# just try to write something to upload this post ignore this ########################################################

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your cluster is not ready yet when you are trying to change the cluster password.
First, you should configure your cluster and ensure that is healthy and then change the password.
The default username and password for Elasticsearch is "`elastic`" and "`changeme`".